# How to verify a method call through a functional interface with Mockito?

Tags: java-8, mockito, verify, functional-interface

I'm using a Supplier to instantiate a field thread safe while avoiding consecutive calls to the synchronized method.

```
class MyClass extends AbstractClassWithContext {

    Supplier<Foo> fooGetter;
    Foo foo;    

    public MyClass() {
        this.fooGetter = this::initFoo;
    }

    Foo getFoo(){
        return fooGetter.get();
    }

    synchonized Foo initFoo(){
        if(Objects.isNull(this.foo)) {
            this.foo = getContext().getFoo();
        }
        this.fooGetter = () -> this.foo;
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

When I'm running my Unit Tests I want to make sure that initFoo() is called exactly once. Sadly `verify(classUnderTest, times(1)).initFoo()` does not register that initFoo is entered. I debugged this and calling `getFoo()` does in turn enter initFoo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your test code looks something like this:

```
MyClass spiedOnObject = spy(new MyClass());
spiedOnObject.getFoo();
verify(spiedOnObject , times(1)).initFoo();
```

The problem is that `this.fooGetter = this::initFoo;` is called before you start spying on the object. At this point `this` refers to the real object, not to the spy. And that reference is captured when the method reference is created. Therefore the call cannot be registered.

Comment: I moved the assignment to the field declaration but this does not change the outcome.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich Because that doesn't change the situation. Only calls after `spy(new MyClass());` will be registered.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich I'm afraid you can't. The problem is that at construction time `this`  points to the real object, not to the spy. And that reference is captured when the method reference is created.